# BibLatex warning as below. Any clue? Thanks

Tags: biblatex, errors

Here is what I want to accomplish, i.e., apa-style citation

```
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
```

But I received the following error message:

> Package biblatex warning: No "backend" specified, using Biber backend. 
>   To use BibTex, load biblatex with the "backend=bibtex" option.
>
> !Latex Error: Command \bibhand already defined
>                 Or name \end... illegal, see p. 192 of the manual.

I have no clue what this means.

Comment: And can you please post a *complete*, minimal document allowing us to reproduce the problem? The first warning is harmless as it just informs you that `biber` will be the backend used; the error indicates that you are loading some other package that has defined `\bibhang` and we need the minimal document to see where the problem might be.